# How can I install the Equinox theme?

Tags: 11.10, themes, software-sources

I'm following the instructions on [this page](http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/04/equinox-adds-3-more-themes-ppa-for.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-equinox equinox-theme
```

But I'm getting:

```
E: Unable to locate package equinox-theme
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this.  No accepted answers, and the OP has 'switched to Debian' per comment.

Answer (score 7):

Equinox is not available for 11.10, and it will only show up in the PPA for 11.04 and below.

The reason it is not available is because the entire equinox engine would need to be ported to GTK+ 3.x, which is not a trivial matter. It will probably be a while if it ever happens at all.

Comment: Is it only a matter or time? If not, why?

Comment: It's a matter of *developer* time.  Being open-source, that means it could be a matter of *your* time if you want it to be ☺.  When someone wants to port it, it'll be ported.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this may help you:
http://www.linuxnov.com/equinox-theme-with-faenza-icon-theme-how-to-install-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/

Let us know if it worked!

Comment: Switched to Debian, sorry. ;-)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.