# Equinox theme widgets in Unity don't appear in the GTK+ theme dropdown list

Tags: 11.10, themes, gtk

I installed the Equinox theme from the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-equinox
```

I have used gnome-tweak-tool to change the window borders to Equinox Evolution Squared but the Equinox theme doesn't appear in the 'GTK+ theme' drop-down option list.

My question is how can I enable the Equinox widgets?

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 and using Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Equinox is not available in ubuntu 11.10 because the equinox engine hasn't been ported to gtk3 as explained in this question [How can I install the Equinox theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65922/how-can-i-install-the-equinox-theme). 
So it won't appear in the gtk theme menu of gnome-tweak-tool